# How to map a class A that inherits from base class using AutoMapper in c#

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a class GetData

```
public class GetData
{
  public FooClass PrevData {get;set;}
  public FooClass NewData {get;set;}
}

public class FooClass: Class B{}


public class B
{
  public string varC;
  public string varD;
  public string varE;
}
```

I need to use automapper to map class GetData's PrevDataA's fields to Class C's properties. I will then use class C to store data in database.

```
public class C
{ 
    public Data data {get;set;}
    public string var_e;
}

public class Data
{
    public string var_c;
    public string var_d;
}
```

I have tried these two :

```
CreateMap<GetData,C>()
.ConvertUsing(src => src.PrevData.Select (x => new C
{
      var_e = x.varE;
      varData= new Data()
          {
            var_c = varC;
            var_d = varD;
          }}));
}
```

Here I get an error on 'select' that testClass does not contain definition for 'Select'.

Also, I have tried using below:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Data.var_c, src => src.MapFrom(src.PrevData.VarC))
```

This is also giving an error saying :

```
Expression "dest => dest.Data.var_C" must resolve top level member and not any child's properties. You can Forpath, a custom resolver on the childtype or the AfterMap option instead.
```

Can anyone help in using ForPath or this.

Comment: By which logic should an object of `A` be mapped to an object of `C`? Please [edit] your question to include a full example of an instance of `A` and how it should be mapped to an object of `C`.

Comment: @Progman I have edited the question. I want to map class A's variableA's properties to class C's properties .

Comment: You haven't posted any example. Please [edit] your question to include an example `A` object and how it should mapped to the `C` object (which value should be saved where). It is unclear how the mapping should be as the class `A` has two fields of type `TestClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the mapping for the properties/fields `C.data` and `C.var_e` manually with the [`ForMember()`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Projection.html?highlight=ForMember#projection) configuration of `CreateMap()`. The configuration can look like this:

```
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<GetData, C>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.var_e, i => i.MapFrom(src => src.PrevData.varE))
       .ForMember(dest => dest.data, i => i.MapFrom(src => new Data 
       {
           var_c = src.PrevData.varC,
           var_d = src.PrevData.varD
       }));
});
```

This will say that for the target `C.var_e` field, use the value of `src.PrevData.varE`. And for the `C.data` field, create a new `Data` instance with the filled `var_c` and `var_d` fields with values from `src.PrevData.varC` and `src.PrevData.varD`.

See the following example:

```
GetData getData = new GetData { 
    NewData = new FooClass {
        varC = "newData_C",
        varD = "newData_D",
        varE = "newData_E"
    },
    PrevData = new FooClass {
        varC = "prevData_C",
        varD = "prevData_D",
        varE = "prevData_E"
    }
};

C target = mapper.Map<C>(getData);
Console.WriteLine(target.var_e);
if (target.data != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(target.data.var_c);
    Console.WriteLine(target.data.var_d);
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("target.data is NULL");
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
prevData_E
prevData_C
prevData_D
```